# Transfer Learning in domains other than Image processing and NLP

Tags: machine-learning, propensity-scores, artificial-intelligence, transfer-learning

Can Transfer Learning be applied in domains other than Image processing or NLP? I am trying to apply it on clickstream data (for propensity modeling). Any reference would be greatly appreciated.